# How can I dynamically render an array passed as a prop in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I am trying to pass this data to a component in vue. I can get the data in the child component, and can render the array, or access each object properties by calling `products[0].name`, but I am looking to render each object separately in a `v-for` loop. please help!!

parent component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome To Our Shop</h1>
    <div class="products">
      <div v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.name">
        <div><ShopItem v-bind:products="products" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ShopItem from "../components/Shop/ShopItem";
export default {
  name: "Shop",
  components: { ShopItem },
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          name: "Basic Deck",
          price: 7,
          description:
            "The Basic Deck includes 68 cards: 10 cards in each of six categories, three icon legend cards, five blank cards for developing your own backstory elements, and instructions.",
          image: require("@/assets/Draeorc.png"),
        },
        {
          name: "Card Bundle",
          price: 10,
          description:
            "The Card Bundle includes the Basic Deck, Technical Booster, Mystical Booster and instructions as a single self-printable PDF.",
          image: require("@/assets/Twilight.png"),
        },
        {
          name: "Full Bundle with Box",
          price: 12,
          description:
            "The Full Bundle includes the Basic Deck, Technical Booster, Mystical Booster, instructions and tuck box as a single self-printable PDF.",
          image: require("@/assets/Orig_Godbringer.png"),
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

child component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="product-container">
    <div>
      <h2>{{ products[0].name }}</h2> //this is where I want to call on the name
      <div class="card-container">
        <img src="../../assets/Draeorc.png" alt="cards" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ShopItem",
  props: ["products"],
};
</script>
```

Comment: try `v-bind:products="product"` (without `s`)

Comment: didn't work initially but after tinkering with it a little but it worked!! thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
  <div v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.name">
    <div><ShopItem v-bind:products="products" /></div>
  </div>
```

your code does not make sense why?

> because you want to go through the array which is here products and
> show each item inside the products array. When you go through the
> array, an item which is right for that iteration will be passed to
> `ShopItem` component and no need to access index by using
> `products[index]`

so it is better to do the following

```
<div><ShopItem v-bind:product="product" /></div>
```

Therefore, your `ShopItem` component will have access to a product one at the time when it goes through the `v-for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Change

```js
v-bind:products="products"
```

to

```js
v-bind:products="product"
```

since you are using for-of loop

and on child component, change:

```js
products[0].name
```

to

```
products.name
```

and since the property is an object, not an array, it's better to change your property name to `product` instead of `products`

So you will have this on parent component:

```html
<div v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.name">
    <div><ShopItem :product="product" /></div>
    // :product is a shorthand for v-bind:product
</div>
```

and this on child component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="product-container">
    <div>
      <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2> //this is where I want to call on the name
      <div class="card-container">
        <img src="../../assets/Draeorc.png" alt="cards" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ShopItem",
  props: ["product"],
};
</script>
```